# Font size does not resize when text is to long

Tags: iphone

I am having a label with text size 13 (too large just to trigger the error). Why wont it resize when the content is too big?

Taken from `loadView`:

```
tempLblSummaryText.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
tempLblSummaryText.numberOfLines = 2;
tempLblSummaryText.minimumFontSize = 8;
tempLblSummaryText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
```

All it does is to keep the size 13 and add `...` behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tempLblSummaryText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

This will reduce the font size as necessary (will not be smaller than `minimumFontSize`). Unfortunately, this does not work with multiline. So you need to set the `numberOfLines` to 1. If you want to reduce font size dynamically in multiline, then [this](http://www.11pixel.com/blog/28/resize-multi-line-text-to-fit-uilabel-on-iphone/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check it out on this site:
http://www.11pixel.com/blog/28/resize-multi-line-text-to-fit-uilabel-on-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`[label sizeToFit];`

I think you can specify max and/or min size, not sure though.